# Python PySerial readline function wrong use

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using a script importing PySerial
to read from COM4

messages I would like to intercept end with a couple of #

so I tried to use

```
bus.readline(eol='##')
```

where bus is my connection.

I expected to read like:

1. *#*3##
2. *#*3##
3. *#*3##

Unfortunalyy I found also

1. *#*1##*1*1*99##

that I expected to read spleetted into 2 lines

1. *#*1##
2. *1*1*99##

Clearly readline is not working but why?

Comment: I never used PySerial, but if it works like you said, it might interpret those two '#' at the middle of "*#*1##*1*1*99##" as an EOL.

Comment: resolved using EnhancedSerial into pySerial including readline function re-implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readline()` method in pyserial reads one character at a time and compares it to the EOL character. You cannot specify multiple characters as the EOL. You'll have to read in and then split later using `string.split()` or `re.split()`

Comment: resolved using EnhancedSerial into pySerial including readline function re-implemented.